# Optimization in $L_1$, does this make sense?

Tags: optimization, banach-spaces, calculus-of-variations

I'd like to find a probability distribution $f(x)$ on the unit interval $[0,1]$ that obeys a given set of moment constraints, e.g. $\int_0^1 xf(x) dx = \mu_0$ for some given $\mu_0$, and so forth.  I'd like the distribution for which $\int_0^1 \sqrt{f_c(x)} dx$, where $f_c$ is the absolutely continuous part of $f$, is as large as possible.  What vector space should I consider this over?  Should it be $L_1$?

As an example, if I only know a constraint on the first moment $\int_0^1 xf(x) dx = \mu_0$, then by discretizing $f$, I would "guess" that the worst-case distribution takes the form $f(x) = \frac{1}{4(\lambda_1+\lambda_2x)^2}$ for suitable $\lambda_i$'s.  Is there a way to make this argument formal?

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the $\left(\mu_n\right)_{n=0}^\infty$, you can constrain the moment generating function and optimize your $\int \sqrt{f_c(x)} dx$. You should make sure the integral exists, that would determine the underlying vector space...

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question to add an example when we only know one moment constraint.